# background 1200 на 2000

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: найденный мною макет в интернете был сделан в размерах 1200 (высота) на 2000 (ширина). Начал делать фоновую картинку, но она не выстраивается под те размеры (ибо экран у меня 1368 на 720 (px)). Скриншот самого макета ниже. Прошу помочь, если кто-нибудь знает решение. P.s background-size не помогает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.main{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/574aa9aab6ec4154fba6c2fd.jpg);
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

background-size всегда и везде работал , пример работы есть как в сниппете так и можно посмотреть и в [codepen](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/beqNZN?editors=110), только вопрос не в  этом а для чего сайты грузить тяжёлыми изображениями ? ,и кстати [вот](https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/574aa9aab6ec4154fba6c2fd.jpg) оригинал изображения мною использованного ,3750х2500 - это внушительный размер

Comment: Ну, соглашусь по поводу загрузки. Да и с bg-size'ом тоже раньше проблем не было. Но вот почему-то именно сейчас...

Comment: И верно - работает. Видимо что-то с высотой не так сделал. По-крайней мере у html не указывал.