# background'a не хватает на всю страницу

Tags: html, css

По сути, продолжение предыдущего вопроса ([background 1200 на 2000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539006/background-1200-%D0%BD%D0%B0-2000)). Проблема с фоном была решена, сверстал логотип и меню... И тут же появилась проблема. Фона "не хватает" на всю страницу (см. скриншот). Прошу помочь, если кто знает, как решить. Заранее спасибо.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Оформите свой код здесь https://jsfiddle.net или здесь http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Почему мы не использовать градиент? для создания точно такого же эффекта??

Comment: background-size:100% 100%; - я уже писал это вам

Comment: @LenovoID да, но на всю страницу он упорно не хотел растягиваться

Comment: Андрей вы мне исходники можете передать ? На почту или в облако , со всеми изображениями и с css html и со всем что у вас есть , я это решу без всяких repeat

Comment: @LenovoID да, могу. Скажите данные.

Comment: lenovonuj@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы не зафиксировать фон:

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

ну или включить повторяемость фона по оси y:

```
background-repeat: repeat-y
```

Comment: С репитом делать не хотел, не очень смотрится

Answer (score 1):

Сделать размытие с переходом в фоновый цвет по бокам или использовать `background-size: cover;`

Comment: И еще background-size: center center;